# Firebase Cloud Functions V2: The request was not authorized to invoke this service

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to call a callable cloud function (which is already deployed) from a client app and getting this error on the GCP logs:

```
{
httpRequest: {9}
insertId: "647865c20002422d2d32b259"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/faker-app-flutter-firebase-dev/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-06-01T09:32:50.154902339Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "WARNING"
spanId: "11982344486849947204"
textPayload: "The request was not authorized to invoke this service. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#401"
timestamp: "2023-06-01T09:32:50.138090Z"
trace: "projects/faker-app-flutter-firebase-dev/traces/ddcb5a4df500af085b7a7f6f89a72ace"
traceSampled: true
}
```

[image]

The same function works correctly from the Firebase Local Emulator, so I assume this is a permissions issue related to IAM and service accounts (I still don't understand too well how IAM works).

Here is my code:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import * as functions from "firebase-functions/v2"
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";

// https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1532
if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
  admin.initializeApp()
}

export const deleteAllUserJobs = functions.https.onCall(async (context: functions.https.CallableRequest) => {
  const uid = context.auth?.uid
  if (uid === undefined) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unauthenticated", "You need to be authenticated to perform this action")
  }
  const firestore = admin.firestore()
  const collectionRef = firestore.collection(`/users/${uid}/jobs`)
  const collection = await collectionRef.get()
  logger.debug(`Deleting ${collection.docs.length} docs at "/users/${uid}/jobs"`)
  // transaction version
  await firestore.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
      for (const doc of collection.docs) {
          transaction.delete(firestore.doc(`/users/${uid}/jobs/${doc.id}`))
      }
  })

  logger.debug(`Deleted ${collection.docs.length} docs at "/users/${uid}/jobs"`)
  return {"success": true}
})
```

The function was deployed with `firebase deploy --only functions`, and I made sure the client app calls this function when the user is already authorized.

According to [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#deploy_the_callable_function):

> If you encounter permissions errors when deploying functions, make sure that the appropriate IAM roles are assigned to the user running the deployment commands.

The docs also link to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#functions), which says:

> Cloud Functions for Firebase permissions
>
> For a list and descriptions of Cloud Functions permissions, refer to
> the IAM documentation.
>
> Be aware that the deployment of functions requires a specific
> configuration of permissions that aren't included in the standard
> Firebase predefined roles. To deploy functions, use one of the
> following options:
>
> ```
> Delegate the deployment of functions to a project Owner.
>
> If you're deploying only non-HTTP functions, then a project Editor can deploy your functions.
>
> Delegate deployment of functions to a project member who has the following two roles:
>     Cloud Functions Admin role (roles/cloudfunctions.admin)
>     Service Account User role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser)
>
> A project Owner can assign these roles to a project member using the Google Cloud Console or gcloud CLI. For detailed steps and
> ```
>
> security implications for this role configuration, refer to the IAM
> documentation.

But like I said, I can successfully deploy the function. It's when I try to execute it that I get an error log.

In summary, what I'm trying to do is quite basic:

1. write a callable cloud function
2. deploy it
3. call it from the client app

When the function runs, it fails with the error above.

Any advice? Do I need to set a specific IAM role?

Comment: So i also have this issue, so i remove the v2, so later i discover me having the owner role also make me deploy in V2... just tell the user to change ur role, they remove after the project is completed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/<project_name>`, find the service account you are using in your firebase project and add the Rol "Cloud Functions Invoker".

[image]

Is like Admin, Editor or Viewer roles are about manipulating the function on GCP (don't allow you to use it) and Invoker allows that account to invoke the function.

Consider that you may need to initialize again your Firebase project in Firebase cli and that you may need to delete and upload again the cloud functions.

Answer (score 3):

After much trial and error, I managed to get it working by adding the "Cloud Functions Invoker" role to the `firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com` principal in the IAM & Admin page:

[image]

Comment: Hey there, I'm still running into this issue. I have tried setting a SA on the function and giving that, the default compute SA, the firebase admin SDK SA, the firebase SA, all function and run invoker permissions, nothing, still get 401... trying to call from Flutter (latest SDKs). Any other thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must download *serviceAccountKey.json* in Console. Than, you must do something like this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");


// some code here...

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

// your api...
```